# Using OR operator for multiple variables in NumPy tuple

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to use the following expression when building my tuple to account for multiple variables. How can I use this or a similar expression without the error `tuple must match array size`?  I would like to avoid using elif for each different `k_ewaste_comm` if possible

```
 if k_ewaste_comm_1 or k_ewaste_comm_2 or k_ewaste_comm_3  ==  4 :
        items.append((Address,
             x,
            y,
              x,
              y,
              ReasonCode,
              SRNumber,
             SRNumber,
             FullName,
              ResolutionCode,
              HomePhone,
              created_object,
             CreatedBy,
              UpdatedDate,
              k_ewaste_count_1 or k_ewaste_count_2 or k_ewaste_count_3 
             k_ewaste_comm_1 or k_ewaste_comm2 or k_ewaste_comm_3,
              date_object,
             GISLayer,

            # ServiceNotes,

             Prior_Resolution_Code,
            k_ewaste_name_1,k_ewaste_name_2, k_ewaste_name_3,
            ))
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this variant. Create method

```
def check_it(*args):
    for i in args:
        if i == 4:
            return i
    return 0

k_ewaste_count = check_it(k_ewaste_count_1, k_ewaste_count_2, k_ewaste_count_3)
if k_ewaste_count:
    items.append((Address,
         x,
        y,
          x,
          y,
          ReasonCode,
          SRNumber,
         SRNumber,
         FullName,
          ResolutionCode,
          HomePhone,
          created_object,
         CreatedBy,
          UpdatedDate,
          k_ewaste_count,
         k_ewaste_count,
          date_object,
         GISLayer,

        # ServiceNotes,

         Prior_Resolution_Code,
        k_ewaste_name_1,k_ewaste_name_2, k_ewaste_name_3,
        ))
```